# in laravel: Loaded html elements disappear after a couple seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have this code that is meant to show some lists of items when hovering the menu icons and... it works. But the issue here is that after some seconds if I hover the icons again, they wont load the lists anymore because the html elements disappear. I provide a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SbBP87hR-60CLnEFZwHBgKKgPiY0mMqk/view?usp=sharing) to show how it happens.

I really don't know whats going on with it, here's the code for both the partial and the file itself:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@php
    $loggedUserInfo = Session::get('loggedUserInfo');
    
    $allAnswers = json_decode($loggedUserInfo?->answers, true) ?? [];
    $currentAnswer = $allAnswers['M.' . str_replace(' ', '-', $module->moduleName)] ?? '';
    $currentList = [];
@endphp

<div class="bodySpaceGestion">
    <div style="position: relative; overflow: visible; max-height: 70vh;">
        <div class="toolbar">
            @isset($screen->screenTips)
                <div class="wrapper-logo-toolbar" data-tooltip="{{ $screen->screenTips }}">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="icon">
                        <path
                            d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8zm-1-6h2v-2h-2v2zm0-4h2V7h-2v3z" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
            @endisset
            @isset($screen->screenStepByStep)
                <div class="wrapper-logo-toolbar" data-tooltip="{{ $screen->screenStepByStep }}"><img src="/icons/foots.png"
                        alt=""></div>
            @endisset

            @isset($screen->screenExamples)
                <div class="wrapper-logo-toolbar" data-tooltip="{{ $screen->screenExamples }}"><img src="/icons/mind.png"
                        alt=""></div>
            @endisset

            {{-- @isset($relatedStrategicLines)
                <div class="wrapper-logo-toolbar"><img src="/icons/List.png" alt=""></div>
            @endisset --}}

            @isset($screen->screenEResources)
                <div class="wrapper-logo-toolbar" related-id="resources-list"><img src="/icons/connection.png"
                        alt=""></div>
            @endisset

            @isset($screen->screenInfography)
                <div class="wrapper-logo-toolbar" related-id='screen-infography'><img src="/icons/template.png"
                        alt=""></div>
            @endisset

            @isset($screen->screenDownload)
                <div class="wrapper-logo-toolbar" related-id='screen-downloads'><img src="/icons/downloadable.png"
                        alt=""></div>
            @endisset

            @isset($screen->screenAudio)
                <div class="wrapper-logo-toolbar" related-id='screen-audio'><img class='logo-toolbar' src="/icons/audio.png"
                        alt=""></div>
            @endisset
            @isset($screen->screenVideo)
                <div class="wrapper-logo-toolbar" related-id='screen-video'><img src="/icons/video.png" alt="">
                </div>
            @endisset
        </div>
        <div class="empty-corner">
            {{-- possible hover options containers --}}
            @isset($screen->screenEResources)
                <div id="resources-list" style="display:none;">
                    @include('partials._resourceList', ['list' => $screen->screenEResources])
                </div>
                @endif

                @isset($screen->screenVideo)
                    <div style="display:none;" id='screen-video'>
                        @include('partials._resourceList', ['list' => $screen->screenEResources])
                    </div>
                    @endif

                    @isset($screen->screenAudio)
                        <div style="display:none;" id='screen-audio'>
                            <audio controls>
                                <source src="{{ asset($screen->screenAudio) }}" type="audio/mpeg">
                            </audio>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                        @isset($screen->screenInfography)
                            <div style="display:none;" id='screen-infography'>
                                <img width="95%" height="315" src="{{ asset($screen->screenInfography) }}" type="audio/mpeg">
                            </div>
                            @endif



                            {{-- End of hover options containers  --}}

                        </div>
                    </div>



                <script>
          
                    const iconContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper-logo-toolbar");
                    const emptyCorner = document.querySelector(".empty-corner");
                    let tooltipTimeout;
                    console.log(iconContainers);


                    iconContainers.forEach(iconContainer => {

                        iconContainer.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
                            const tooltipText = iconContainer.getAttribute("data-tooltip");

                            const relatedId = iconContainer.getAttribute("related-id");
                            console.log('hovering ' + relatedId);

                            const relatedItem = document.getElementById(relatedId);
                            console.log('then: ' + relatedItem);

                            const emptyCornerChildren = emptyCorner.children;
                            for (const child of emptyCornerChildren) {
                                child.style.display = 'none';
                            }
                            if (relatedItem === null) {
                                console.log('showing text');
                                emptyCorner.textContent = tooltipText;

                            } else {
                                console.log('showing ' + relatedId);
                                relatedItem.style.display = 'block';
                            }

                            emptyCorner.style.opacity = 1;
                            clearTimeout(tooltipTimeout);
                        });

                        iconContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
                            const relatedId = iconContainer.getAttribute("related-id");

                            const relatedItem = document.getElementById(relatedId);
                            tooltipTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                                emptyCorner.style.opacity = 0;
                                if (relatedItem != null) {
                                    relatedItem.style.display = 'none';
                                }
                            }, 200); // Delayed fade-out time
                        });
                    });

                    emptyCorner.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {

                        if (emptyCorner.style.opacity != 0) {
                            clearTimeout(tooltipTimeout);
                            emptyCorner.style.opacity = 1;

                        }
                    });

                    emptyCorner.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {

                        tooltipTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                            emptyCorner.style.opacity = 0;

                        }, 200); // Delayed fade-out time
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: did not read all your code. When you hover to the assets, do they perform ajax/fetch request? Or all items to be displayed were already fetched on reload?

Comment: If all items were fetched during reload, just to `on hover > display:block` else `display:none` Though you would need to write the correct code for this.

Comment: Or add/remove css with styles displaying/hiding items with transistion

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth yes its okay, I understand. Regarding your question, there's no ajax usage since I'm passing the variables through the `->with()` command in the controller. So yes, im passing them on reload and as you said i wrote the code so that it would perform display block or display none depending on the case. As I said, the code works perfectly during some seconds, then it doesn't. Ill edit the code uploaded to something more relevant

Comment: instead of `setTimeout => adding opacity` do `on mouseenter => add css-class` on `mouseleave => remove css-class`. Inside css-class, add your opacity with transition. I am not really that good with css so you might need to do research on that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short story I was using:

```js
if (relatedItem === null) {
    console.log('showing text');
    emptyCorner.textContent = tooltipText;
}
```

This caused the inner html to be erased and, therefore, would not be rendering the list of resources or any other screen attribute anymore. To fix it, I simply added another div with data-tooltip that contained the text.